# None в рекурсивной функции, Python3.P

Tags: python-3.x

Занимаюсь Python3, попробовал сделать рекурсивную функцию, которая говорит просто числе или нет, но когда ей вводишь нечетные числа, она почти всегда выдает None, что делать?

```
def primes(num, numbers):

    if num % numbers == 0:
        return False
    elif numbers == int(sqrt(num) + 1):
        return True
    else:
        primes(num, numbers + 1)

num = int(input())

print( primes(num, 2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Так ничего же не возвращается в последнем условии, отсюда и `None`. В большинстве случаев условие заводит в последнюю ветку, и хоть сколько там будет рекурсий основная все равно ничего не возвращает.
Нужно добавить `return`:

```
return primes(num, numbers + 1)
```